# Django memory leak

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm developping a python app which uses `Django ORM` as standalone to manage a database, but I'm facing a big memory issue. I've found that the part which is causing this issue is:

```
ports_list_save = []
    for host in results['hosts']:
        for protocol in results['hosts'][host]['protocols']:
            for port in results['hosts'][host]['protocols'][protocol]:
                current_port = history.Port(number=int(port), 
                                            protocol=protocol, 
                                            state=results['hosts'][host]['protocols'][protocol][port]['state'], 
                                            service='', 
                                            version='', 
                                            address=history.Ip.objects.get(scan=self.scan, address=host))
                ports_list_save.append(current_port)
    history.Port.objects.bulk_create(ports_list_save)
```

This part worked fine with 154 hosts and 150 ports per hosts (23000) objects to save, but now I'm trying it with 1000 ports and my computer's memory explode each time.

One more thing, I'm NOT running `Django` in debug mode, so the memory doesn't come from
`django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base.DatabaseWrapper`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You've increased the number of data ~10 times so you should expect the increase in memory usage ~10 times. Is something unusual happening here? I.e. what makes you think there's a memory leak?

Comment: The process use more than 2Go RAM + 1Go SWAP to process 100k * 3 strings of max 10 Char, sounds like too much for me.

Comment: But you are not dealing with strings. These are Python objects. Every small piece of data takes memory and they can use kilobytes. It doesn't look like a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of data you still may need to load & process it in chunks, try this:

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 23000
ports_list_save = []
for host in results['hosts']:
    for protocol in results['hosts'][host]['protocols']:
        for port in results['hosts'][host]['protocols'][protocol]:
            current_port = history.Port(number=int(port), 
                                        protocol=protocol, 
                                        state=results['hosts'][host]['protocols'][protocol][port]['state'], 
                                        service='', 
                                        version='', 
                                        address=history.Ip.objects.get(scan=self.scan, address=host))
            ports_list_save.append(current_port)
            if len(ports_list_save) > CHUNK_SIZE:
                history.Port.objects.bulk_create(ports_list_save)
                ports_list_save = []
if ports_list_save:   
    history.Port.objects.bulk_create(ports_list_save)
```

Comment: Works pretty fine, thx :).
Btw, i found something which worked too, it's calling "gc.collect()" at the end of every "for host in results['hosts']" loop. Is it a bad thing? Which way is the best?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Calling `gc.collect()` won't hurt anything, but I'm not sure if you get much benefit from it.  I'd leave it out, unless you see a significant improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem and ended up with this solution:

```
class BulkCreateManager(object):

    model = None
    chunk_size = None
    instances = None

    def __init__(self, model, chunk_size=None, *args):
        self.model = model
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size
        self.instances = []

    def append(self, instance):
        if self.chunk_size and len(self.instances) > self.chunk_size:
            self.create()
            self.instances = []

        self.instances.append(instance)

    def create(self):
        self.model.objects.bulk_create(self.instances)



ports_list_save = BulkCreateManager(history.Port, 23000)
for host in results['hosts']:
    for protocol in results['hosts'][host]['protocols']:
        for port in results['hosts'][host]['protocols'][protocol]:
            current_port = history.Port(number=int(port), 
                                        protocol=protocol, 
                                        state=results['hosts'][host]['protocols'][protocol][port]['state'], 
                                        service='', 
                                        version='', 
                                        address=history.Ip.objects.get(scan=self.scan, address=host))
            ports_list_save.append(current_port)

ports_list_save.create()
```